# A great tutorial of mysql to jump right in?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I will use mysql as a database choice with my java. What is the best way to learn it quickly and become productive super fast... well I am jsut trying to learn it as I am working on the project involving it. I my  goal is

- to be able to create/administer/design tables for  Mysql database
- program in Java against it (with **tomcat**)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this site: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html

Also I suggest you download a front end for MySQL, Grab one here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Are you that set on Java or have you considered using .net? If you know any .net, you can run your stuff on Linux or Mac using Mono. Not great, but it can run .net v2 code.

In my experience Java is more difficult to learn and master than C#.

Answer (score 1):

Mysqls own web site is very good. Even their command reference is filled with good examples and user comments such as gotchas under each page (every site should have that IMHO). For example check out the [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/insert.html) command documentation.

Here's a [good beginner tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html) also on that site.

Finally for Java connectivity use [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference.html) as a reference.

I've been using HeidiSQL to view and edit my tables in testing, but it's also cool to get good with the command line initially.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381) are [two](http://www.wbluhm.com/MySQLTut.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look into Hibernate, here is a quick start tutorial
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

Then you'll be able to jump into any INSERT_DBSOFTWARE_HERE which have a jdbc driver, by only knowing HQL language.

If you use http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/ you can model your database with a cool software and only export a table creation file.

So to create/administer/design : MySQL workbench
To program in Java : Hibernate

Good luck

Comment: While I agree with this, a solid understanding of native SQL is VERY handy before learning hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sounds like you're asking for two types of information here: 1. how to perform basic operations on a MySQL database and 2. how to interact with a MySQL database programmatically from within Java.

For the first question, these are MySQL basics -- there's [tons](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Beginning-MySQL-Tutorial/) and [tons](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/) of resources for getting started with MySQL and learning how to do the stuff you're describing.

As to the second (interfacing with Java), I'd look into [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jdbc). Try [here](http://www.acm.org/crossroads/columns/ovp/march2001.html) or [here](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381).

Edit:
Here's a dynamic content generation [tutorial](http://www.opensourcetutorials.com/tutorials/Databases/MySQL/tomcat-and-mysql/page1.html) that talks about getting Tomcat to work with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the standard method of using Google, you can also find quite a few decent tutorials popping up on YouTube nowadays.
As for web recommendations here's a couple that go a little beyond the immediate beginner - not strictly tutorials, but they should help a lot (the second is mine I have to confess, but it does have a lot of useful links too)
[Mysql common queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1024)
[Blog on using Mysql](http://www.oxfordtechnotes.co.uk/sqlblog/blog4.php)
To start with, here's a very useful cheat sheet on Mysql
[cheat sheet](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/mysql.php)

Comment: These tutorials ARE GREAT. thanks a lot